# Distributed Tensorflow: CreateSession still waiting

Tags: python, tensorflow, distributed-computing, distributed

Simple script below is launched with args shown in it's header. It behaves differently, but often one of the workers hangs and prints these "CreateSession still waiting for some other task" messages. Why does a new  MonitoredTrainingSession need others? And why don't the others wait for it to start?

```
# #!/bin/bash
# python train.py --job master --task 0 &
# python train.py --job worker --task 0 &
# python train.py --job worker --task 1 &
# python train.py --job worker --task 2 &
import argparse
import tensorflow as tf

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--job', type=str)
parser.add_argument('--task', type=int)
args = parser.parse_args()
hosts = {
    "master": [
        "localhost:2222",
    ],
    "worker": [
        "localhost:2223",
        "localhost:2224",
        "localhost:2225",
    ]
}

nworkers = len(hosts['worker'])
cluster = tf.train.ClusterSpec(hosts)
server = tf.train.Server(cluster, job_name=args.job, task_index=args.task)

with tf.device(f'/job:master/task:0'):
    global_step = tf.train.get_or_create_global_step()
    inc_global_step = tf.assign(global_step, global_step + 1)

if args.job == 'worker':
    hooks = [
        tf.train.StopAtStepHook(last_step=4),
    ]
    with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession(master=server.target,
                                           is_chief=(args.task == 0),
                                           hooks=hooks) as sess:
        while not sess.should_stop():
            print(args.task, sess.run(inc_global_step))
else:
    server.join()
```

It could wait for the chief to init it's variables. But it happens to wait for another non-chief worker too. So, does MonitoredTrainingSession synchronise tasks? If it doesn't, are FIFOQueues the only primitive to do manual synchronisation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, a distributed TensorFlow session will attempt to connect to **all servers** named in the `tf.train.ClusterSpec`, and will block until they respond. This provides a useful barrier that ensures that all workers have become ready to receive computation requests before returning control to the user. This barrier happens before the `MonitoredTrainingSession` code that waits for the chief to initialize variables.

If you don't want your session to wait on all servers (e.g. just wait on tasks in `"/job:ps"` and not the other tasks in `"/job:worker"`, which is a common between-graph deployment strategy), the easiest option is to specify a "device filter" when you create your session. The device filter is a whitelist of (partial) device specifications that determines which tasks a `tf.Session` will contact at startup. For example, the `mnist_replica.py` test [specifies](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/0b0d3c12ace80381f4a44365d30275a9a262609b/tensorflow/tools/dist_test/python/mnist_replica.py#L217) a device filter as part of the `tf.ConfigProto` that is used to configure the session.

Comment: The chief initialises variables on tasks 0, 1, 2 even if task 2 still hasn't launched a session, but it's server is already running. Is it true?

Comment: The variables will be initialized wherever they are placed by a `with tf.device():` block. For example, in your code, the `global_step` will be created on `"/job:master/task:0"`, and no other tasks will have variables. When the `tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession` starts, the task for which `is_chief` is `True` (i.e. `"/job:worker/task:0"`) will run a step to perform the initialization. This initialization step will block until all of the servers respond to a ping (but they need not have started a session). Then all of the other workers will block until the initialization step has completed.