# Distributed Tensorflow : CreateSession still waiting only for different nodes

Tags: python, tensorflow, distributed, grpc

I am trying to get [mnist_replica.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/0b0d3c12ace80381f4a44365d30275a9a262609b/tensorflow/tools/dist_test/python/mnist_replica.py) example work. As per suggestion on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46429766/distributed-tensorflow-createsession-still-waiting) question, I am specifying device filter.

My code works when ps and worker tasks are on the same node. When I try to put ps task on node1 and worker task on node2, I get "CreateSession still waiting".

For example:

**Pseudo Distributed Version (works!)**

Terminal Dump of Node1 (instance 1)

```
node1 $ python mnist_replica.py --worker_hosts=node1:2223 --job_name=ps --task_index=0
Extracting /tmp/mnist-data/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Extracting /tmp/mnist-data/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
Extracting /tmp/mnist-data/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Extracting /tmp/mnist-data/t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
job name = ps
task index = 0
2017-10-10 11:09:16.637006: I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_channel.cc:215] Initialize GrpcChannelCache for job ps -> {0 -> localhost:2222}
2017-10-10 11:09:16.637075: I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_channel.cc:215] Initialize GrpcChannelCache for job worker -> {0 -> node1:2223}
2017-10-10 11:09:16.640114: I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_server_lib.cc:316] Started server with target: grpc://localhost:2222
...
```

Terminal Dump of Node1 (instance 2)

```
node1 $ python mnist_replica.py --worker_hosts=node1:2223 --job_name=worker --task_index=0
Extracting /tmp/mnist-data/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Extracting /tmp/mnist-data/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
Extracting /tmp/mnist-data/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Extracting /tmp/mnist-data/t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
job name = worker
task index = 0
2017-10-10 11:11:12.784982: I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_channel.cc:215] Initialize GrpcChannelCache for job ps -> {0 -> localhost:2222}
2017-10-10 11:11:12.785046: I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_channel.cc:215] Initialize GrpcChannelCache for job worker -> {0 -> localhost:2223}
2017-10-10 11:11:12.787685: I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_server_lib.cc:316] Started server with target: grpc://localhost:2223
Worker 0: Initializing session...
2017-10-10 11:11:12.991784: I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/master_session.cc:998] Start master session 418af3aa5ce103a3 with config: device_filters: "/job:ps" device_filters: "/job:worker/task:0" allow_soft_placement: true
Worker 0: Session initialization complete.
Training begins @ 1507648273.272837
1507648273.443305: Worker 0: training step 1 done (global step: 0)
1507648273.454537: Worker 0: training step 2 done (global step: 1)
...
```

**2 Nodes Distributed ( don't work)**

Terminal Dump of Node1

```
node1 $ python mnist_replica.py --worker_hosts=node2:2222 --job_name=ps --task_index=0
Extracting /tmp/mnist-data/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Extracting /tmp/mnist-data/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
Extracting /tmp/mnist-data/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Extracting /tmp/mnist-data/t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
job name = ps
task index = 0
2017-10-10 10:54:27.419949: I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_channel.cc:215] Initialize GrpcChannelCache for job ps -> {0 -> localhost:2222}
2017-10-10 10:54:27.420064: I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_channel.cc:215] Initialize GrpcChannelCache for job worker -> {0 -> node2:2222}
2017-10-10 10:54:27.426168: I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_server_lib.cc:316] Started server with target: grpc://localhost:2222
...
```

Terminal Dump of Node2

```
node2 $ python mnist_replica.py --ps_hosts=node1:2222 --worker_hosts=node2:2222 --job_name=worker --task_index=0
Extracting /tmp/mnist-data/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Extracting /tmp/mnist-data/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
Extracting /tmp/mnist-data/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Extracting /tmp/mnist-data/t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
job name = worker
task index = 0
2017-10-10 10:51:13.303021: I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_channel.cc:215] Initialize GrpcChannelCache for job ps -> {0 -> node1:2222}
2017-10-10 10:51:13.303081: I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_channel.cc:215] Initialize GrpcChannelCache for job worker -> {0 -> localhost:2222}
2017-10-10 10:51:13.308288: I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_server_lib.cc:316] Started server with target: grpc://localhost:2222
Worker 0: Initializing session...
2017-10-10 10:51:23.508040: I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/master.cc:209] CreateSession still waiting for response from worker: /job:ps/replica:0/task:0
2017-10-10 10:51:33.508247: I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/master.cc:209] CreateSession still waiting for response from worker: /job:ps/replica:0/task:0
...
```

Both nodes run CentOS7, Tensorflow R1.3, Python 2.7. Nodes can talk to each other via ssh, hostnames are correct, firewall is disabled. Anything missing?

Are there any additional steps I need to take to make sure nodes can talk to each other using GRPC?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would better check ClusterSpec and server part. For example, you should check the ip address for node1 and node2, check the port and task index and etc. I want to give specific suggestion but it is hard to give you suggestions without the code. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I just edited my original questions above with termina dump, system information. I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Hmm.. I think if you implement the code similar to url you gave, it's hard to find the error in the code. 
What about check the network connection between node1 and node2? For example, check the port, or ping to node1...

Comment: I test with the code above mnist_replica.py in servers with two nodes, it works well. 
I think it is not the error in code. You would better to check other things.

Comment: Yes. You were right. It was issue related to firewall blocking ports.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was firewall was blocking ports. I disabled firewall on all nodes in questions and issue resolved itself!