# Distributed Tensorflow: Unable to run evaluation-only worker

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to distribute training and evaluation over two machines:

- PC1: training on GPU and parameter server
- PC2: evaluation-only, whenever a new checkpoint is available

To do so, I'm trying to adapt the `tf.contrib.learn.Experiment` framework, but I can't seem to get the cluster specification right.

This is a stripped-down version of my code:

```
def get_schedule(run_config):
  if run_config.task_type == 'ps':
    return 'run_std_server'
  if run_config.task_type == 'worker':
    return 'train'
  if run_config.task_type == 'evaluator':
    return 'continuous_eval'
  if run_config.task_type == 'master':
    return 'train'
  raise ValueError('Unknown task type "{}"'.format(run_config.task_type))

def deeplpr_model_fn(features, labels, mode, cluster_spec={}):
  with tf.device(tf.train.replica_device_setter(cluster=cluster_spec)):
    logits = build_model(features['images'], mode)
  #[...] Standard Estimator setup for training & evaluation
  return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, 
                                    predictions=predictions, 
                                    export_outputs=export_outputs,
                                    loss=loss,
                                    train_op=train_op,
                                    eval_metric_ops=metrics)

def get_experiment(run_config=None, hparams=None):
  # Create the Estimator
  estimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(
    model_fn=lambda features, labels, mode : my_model_fn(features, labels, mode, run_config.cluster_spec),
    model_dir=FLAGS.model_dir,
    config=run_config)
  
  # Set up input functions for training and evaluation
  train_input_fn = lambda : input_fn(tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN, FLAGS.batch_size)
  eval_input_fn = lambda : input_fn(tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL, FLAGS.batch_size)
  
  # Set up the experiment
  experiment = tf.contrib.learn.Experiment(
    estimator=estimator,
    train_input_fn=train_input_fn,
    eval_input_fn=eval_input_fn,
    train_steps=FLAGS.steps,
    eval_steps=None,
    eval_delay_secs=20, # time to wait before running the first evaluation
    train_steps_per_iteration=2000)
  return experiment
```

The main function looks as follows:

```
def distributed_main(unused_argv):
  import json
  # Set up environment variables according to the parameters passed to the process
  TF_CONFIG = {
    'cluster': {
        "worker": [
            "pc1:2222",
        ],
        "ps": [
            "pc1:2223",
        ],
        "evaluator": [
            "pc2:2224",
        ]
    },
    'environment': 'cluster',    
    'task': {
        'type': unused_argv[1].strip(),
        'index': unused_argv[2].strip() if len(unused_argv) > 2 else 0
        }
  }
  os.environ['TF_CONFIG'] = json.dumps(TF_CONFIG)
  
  session_config = tf.ConfigProto(device_filters=device_filters, 
                                  allow_soft_placement=True)
  config = tf.contrib.learn.RunConfig(model_dir=FLAGS.model_dir, 
                                      session_config=session_config)
  schedule = get_schedule(config)
  tf.logging.info('Beginning task {}:{}'.format(config.task_type, config.task_id))
  
  # Run the function
  tf.contrib.learn.learn_runner.run(get_experiment, schedule=schedule, run_config=config)
```

where `unused_argv` contains a job name and optionally an index (defaults to 0).

Running three processes with the appropriate job names and task ids, I can't get the worker go past the session initialization step because it expects `evaluator` to communicate with the chief worker (which it doesn't, if `continuous_eval` is called, apparently).

Researching the issue, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46429766/distributed-tensorflow-createsession-still-waiting) where they suggest to add a `device_filter`, so I tried adding:

```
  device_filters=["/job:ps", "/job:worker"]
  if unused_argv[1] != 'worker':
    device_filters += ['/job:evaluator']
  session_config = tf.ConfigProto(device_filters=device_filters)
  config = tf.contrib.learn.RunConfig(model_dir=FLAGS.model_dir, session_config=session_config)
```

This effectively unlocks the worker and ps, but the evaluator then crashes when attempting to restore the newest checkpoint:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "deeplpr.py", line 431, in <module>
    tf.app.run(main=distributed_main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
  File "C:\Users\1\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 126, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "deeplpr.py", line 420, in distributed_main
    tf.contrib.learn.learn_runner.run(get_experiment, schedule=schedule, run_config=config)
  File "C:\Users\1\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\learn\python\learn\learn_runner.py", line 218, in run
    return _execute_schedule(experiment, schedule)
  File "C:\Users\1\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\learn\python\learn\learn_runner.py", line 46, in _execute_schedule
    return task()
  File "C:\Users\1\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\learn\python\learn\experiment.py", line 573, in continuous_eval
    continuous_eval_predicate_fn=continuous_eval_predicate_fn)
  File "C:\Users\1\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\learn\python\learn\experiment.py", line 533, in _continuous_eval
    hooks=self._eval_hooks)
  File "C:\Users\1\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\learn\python\learn\experiment.py", line 894, in _call_evaluate
    hooks=hooks)
  File "C:\Users\1\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 414, in evaluate
    name=name)
  File "C:\Users\1\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 949, in _evaluate_model
    config=self._session_config)
  File "C:\Users\1\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\evaluation.py", line 209, in _evaluate_once
    session_creator=session_creator, hooks=hooks) as session:
  File "C:\Users\1\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 795, in __init__
    stop_grace_period_secs=stop_grace_period_secs)
  File "C:\Users\1\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 518, in __init__
    self._sess = _RecoverableSession(self._coordinated_creator)
  File "C:\Users\1\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 981, in __init__
    _WrappedSession.__init__(self, self._create_session())
  File "C:\Users\1\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 986, in _create_session
    return self._sess_creator.create_session()
  File "C:\Users\1\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 675, in create_session
    self.tf_sess = self._session_creator.create_session()
  File "C:\Users\1\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 446, in create_session
    init_fn=self._scaffold.init_fn)
  File "C:\Users\1\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\session_manager.py", line 275, in prepare_session
    config=config)
  File "C:\Users\1\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\session_manager.py", line 191, in _restore_checkpoint
    saver.restore(sess, checkpoint_filename_with_path)
  File "C:\Users\1\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 1760, in restore
    {self.saver_def.filename_tensor_name: save_path})
  File "C:\Users\1\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 905, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "C:\Users\1\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1137, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\1\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1355, in _do_run
    options, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\1\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1374, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Cannot assign a device for operation 'save/RestoreV2_1': Operation was explicitly assigned to /job:ps/task:0/device:CPU:0 but available devices are [ /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 ]. Make sure the device specification refers to a valid device.
         [[Node: save/RestoreV2_1 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:ps/task:0/device:CPU:0"](save/Const, save/RestoreV2_1/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2_1/shape_and_slices)]]
```

What is the proper way to designate a worker for evaluation only?
In the logs from Tensorflow, I see that the `RunConfig` used has a parameter `'_evaluation_master': ''`, but I can't find any documentation about it. Is this somehow related? Are there any working examples that show how to distribute experiments separating training and evaluation?

### Update:

As suggested, I added `log_device_placement=True` when defining `session_config`.
The log output, however, seems to crash before logging the device placements:

```
INFO:tensorflow:Waiting 20.000000 secs before starting eval.
INFO:tensorflow:Calling model_fn.
INFO:tensorflow:Done calling model_fn.
INFO:tensorflow:Starting evaluation at 2018-02-19-15:35:04
INFO:tensorflow:Graph was finalized.
2018-02-19 16:35:04.888165: I C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\35\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:140] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from models\test_distributed\model.ckpt-2373
# Here starts the traceback of the error, same as above
```

This is slightly confusing, shouldn't I see the placement log at session creation? And doesn't the `restore` op need the session to run?

Setting `allow_device_placement=True` also didn't change anything in the log and error.

### Update 2:

setting `log_device_placement=True` for *all* machines only logs it in `worker:0` (aka the master), which I assume is the expected behaviour

### Edit:

Updated the code above to reflect how I set `allow_device_placement=True` (Only the main function changed).

Answer (score 1):

On `PC2` add `allow_soft_placement=True` to `session_config`.

```
session_config = tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True)
```

Read [this section](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/using_gpu#using_a_single_gpu_on_a_multi-gpu_system) for more information about this parameter.

> If you would like TensorFlow to automatically choose an existing and
>   supported device to run the operations in case the specified one
>   doesn't exist, you can set allow_soft_placement to True in the
>   configuration option when creating the session

### Update

After taking a closer look at the error logs, I see that the error is fired on this line.

```
tf.contrib.learn.learn_runner.run(
    get_experiment,
    schedule=schedule,
    run_config=config
)
```

so, the `allow_soft_placement=True` should be set in its [`run_config`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/RunConfig#session_config) parameter, like the following.

```
config = tf.contrib.learn.RunConfig(
    model_dir=FLAGS.model_dir,
    session_config=tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True)
)
```

Comment: @GPhilo mea culpa. I meant `allow_soft_placement`. see my update.

Comment: Yes, I guessed it ;) Adding that, however, doesn't change the error message or the logs before that (besides showing in the logged configuration that `allow_soft_placement` i indeed set to `True`)

Comment: See my edited main function, I was already setting it in the "right" run_config